# Evaluate $\sum_{i=0}^{100}\binom{k}{i}\binom{M-k}{100-i}\frac{k-i}{M-100}.$

Tags: combinatorics

Find the value of $$\sum_{i=0}^{100}\dbinom{k}{i}\dbinom{M-k}{100-i}\frac{k-i}{M-100},$$ where $M-k>100,k>100$.

My approach: The Vandermonde's identity states that $$\sum_{i=0}^r\dbinom{m}{i}\dbinom{n}{r-i}=\dbinom{m+n}{r}$$ for any non-negative integer $m,n,r$.

Therefore setting $m=k$, $n=M-k$ and $r=100$, in the Vandermonde's identity we have, $$\sum_{i=0}^{100}\dbinom{k}{i}\dbinom{M-k}{100-i}=\dbinom{M}{100}.$$

This implies that $$\sum_{i=0}^{100}\dbinom{k}{i}\dbinom{M-k}{100-i}\frac{k-i}{M-100}$$ $$=\frac{k}{M-100}\sum_{i=0}^{100}\dbinom{k}{i}\dbinom{M-k}{100-i}-\frac{1}{M-100}\sum_{i=0}^{100}\dbinom{k}{i}\dbinom{M-k}{100-i}i$$$$=\frac{k}{M-100}\dbinom{M}{100}-\frac{1}{M-100}\sum_{i=0}^{100}\dbinom{k}{i}\dbinom{M-k}{100-i}i.$$

I need help in evaluating the expression $$\sum_{i=0}^{100}\dbinom{k}{i}\dbinom{M-k}{100-i}i.$$

Answer (score 2):

$$-\frac{1}{M-100}\sum_{i=0}^{100}{{k}\choose{i}}{{M-k}\choose{100-i}}i$$$$=-\frac{k}{M-100}\sum_{i=0}^{100}{{k-1}\choose{i-1}}{{M-k}\choose{100-i}}$$

Setting $i-1 \mapsto i$ yields:
$$=-\frac{k}{M-100}\sum_{i=0}^{99}{{k-1}\choose{i}}{{M-k}\choose{99-i}}$$$$=\color{red}{-\frac{k}{M-100}{{M-1}\choose{99}}}$$